# How to add timezone into log

Tags: c#, format, timezone, nlog

I would like to see the following:

`2021-12-20 13:29:30+03`

So, i've added this option to layout property in  FileTarget class:

`${date:format=yyyy-MM-ddTHH\\:mm\\:ss}`

...but i got this:

`2021-12-20T13:29:30`

What did I write wrong?

Comment: Isparia, this is the surprise. If you follow the link and compare how I wrote the format and how it is written there, then everything is correct. The question is why it doesn't work

Comment: have you tried replacing the `"T"` in your format string with a `" "` ?

Comment: Franz Gleichmann, yes, i've tried, just this string: `2021-12-20 13:29:30`, without timezone

Comment: no. think about it. you have a T in your output where you want a space instead. so you should replace the T in your pattern, which is not a placeholder but is literally interpreted as `T`, with a space. meaning:  `${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\\:mm\\:ss}`

Comment: Yes, I understood and edited my answer, sorry.

Comment: and now add `zzz` => `${date:format=yyyy-MM-ddTHH\\:mm\\:sszzz}` to your format string and you should be golden

Comment: Yes, i wrote like this: `${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\\:mm\\:sszzzz}` and it works fine! Thank you! Happy New Year!